# Remove/Add widgets from/to the Available Widgets pool

Tags: widgets, wp-admin

Is it possible to remove/add widgets from/to the Available Widgets pool (either by plugin or editing core files)?

There are 3 widget files located at:

/wp-includes/widgets.php

/wp-admin/widgets.php

/wp-admin/includes/widgets.php

I have tried to change both the code and the widget variables but nothing happened.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function [`unregister_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget) to remove widgets.

E.g. you can remove the Calendar widget with:

```
function my_widgets_init() {
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' );
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init');
```

To add widgets, use the [`Widgets API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).